# import error in latex - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, latex, jinja2

latex==0.6.1 and Jinja2==2.7.3 are installed on my system but when I try to import latex this error shows up

```
>>> import latex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "latex.py", line 2, in <module>
    from latex.jinja2 import make_env
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

Please help!

Comment: Stop calling your file `latex.py`.

Comment: Also in your own code don't access `jinja2` from the `latex` module - explicitely import from jinja2 where you need it (=> replace "from latex.jinja2 import make_env" witth "from jinja2 import make_env")

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: `latex.jinja2` is not the same module as `jinja2`, and I don't think `jinja2` has a `make_env` function. `latex.jinja2` is [this thing](https://github.com/mbr/latex/blob/master/latex/jinja2.py).

Comment: OK I stand corrected....